# MouseEnter event does not fires when the menustrip is opened

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseenter, menustrip

I have a menuStrip with several items, and a button in other part of the form. When the mouse enters the button, it does something (MouseEnter event). The issue I´m getting is that when the menustrip is opened, if the mouse enters the button, the MouseEnter event is not fired. Is there any way to fire while the menustrip is opened?

To see this graphically, this is what I´m doing:

[image]

I have a menustrip, and for each parent menu item, there is a button. The button will be above it, so the only visible part of the menustrip will be the container with their child items.

Now, when the mouse enters the button, for example "System", it performs a click in the menu item. Thats why the container appears. But once opened, if I want to open any other container of the other parents, I have to click first to lose focus. Then, what I want to achive is to do this without having to click.

The behavior i want is like the one the menustrip has. For example, if System is opened, and the Mouse enters in Clients, it closes automatically System and opens Clients.

[image]

Comment: which type of fire will you want like that..key press, function key and so????????????

Comment: How will the event fire when your menustrip is in focus??? You can focus one control at a time.

Comment: just select the menuStrip and press the f4 function key...open the property dialog ...go to event and select any type you want.......

Comment: I just want the same behavior as when the mouse enters a different menu item parent. It just opens that one and closes the rest. So, when the mouse is over the button i want to close all opened menutrip items. This is, because the button will be the one that opens an specific menuitem..

Comment: If you can show the images so we can better understand your problem.

Comment: share your coding part for better understand

Comment: Added guys, hope its more easy to understand now.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to implement IMessageFilter in your app, and re-direct the desired mouse event. I have had to do this with MouseWheel events to prevent them getting sen to a non-responsive control in the Z-order.

Comment: Thanks @PieterGeerkens. Don´t you have by the way a code example so as to show me?

Comment: I am gun-shy right now, from being penalized for posting links to other web sites (where I first saw this), and for posting maybe comments that moderators regard as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this is a valid answer:

```
#region IMessageFilter implementation
/// <summary> Redirect WM_MouseWheel messages to window under mouse.</summary>
    /// <remarks>Redirect WM_MouseWheel messages to window under mouse (rather than 
/// that with focus) with adjusted delta.
/// <see cref="http://www.flounder.com/virtual_screen_coordinates.htm"/>
/// Dont forget to add this to constructor:
///             Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
///</remarks>
    /// <param name="m">The Windows Message to filter and/or process.</param>
    /// <returns>Success (true) or failure (false) to OS.</returns>
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSetAttribute(
        System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")]
    bool IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage(ref Message m) {
        // Determine window and control at these coordinates.
  //var pos   = WindowsMouseInput.GetPointLParam(m.LParam);
        var hWnd  = WindowFromPoint( WindowsMouseInput.GetPointLParam(m.LParam) );
        var ctl   = Control.FromHandle(hWnd);
  if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero  &&  hWnd != m.HWnd  &&  ctl != null) {
    switch(m.Msg) {
      default:  return false;
      case (int)WM.MOUSEWHEEL:
        DebugTracing.Trace(TraceFlag.ScrollEvents, true," - {0}.WM.MouseWheel: {1}", 
                                                    Host.Name, ((WM)m.Msg).ToString()); 
        if (ctl is MapPanel) {
          var keyState    = WindowsMouseInput.GetKeyStateWParam(m.WParam);
          var mult            = keyState.HasFlag(MouseKeys.Control) ? 5 : 1;
          keyState            = keyState &= ~MouseKeys.Control;
          var wheelDelta    = WindowsMouseInput.WheelDelta(m.WParam);
          // forward delta of +/- 30 instead of +/- 120; 30/120 == 1/4
          var newWparam   = WindowsMouseInput.WParam((Int16)(mult*wheelDelta/4), keyState);
          SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, newWparam, m.LParam);
          return true;
        } else if (ctl is MapFormOverview) {
          var keyState    = WindowsMouseInput.GetKeyStateWParam(m.WParam);
          var wheelDelta    =  WindowsMouseInput.WheelDelta(m.WParam);
          // forward delta of +/- 54 instead of +/- 120
          // 54 = 3 * 18 (default point height in pixels?); 54/120 == 9/20
          var newWparam   = WindowsMouseInput.WParam((Int16)(wheelDelta*9/20), keyState);
          SendMessage(hWnd, m.Msg, newWparam, m.LParam);
          return true;
        }
        break;
    }
  }
  return false;
    }
#region Extern declarations
/// <summary>P/Invoke declaration for user32.dll.WindowFromPoint</summary>
    /// <remarks><see cref="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558(v=vs.85).aspx"/></remarks>
    /// <param name="pt">(Sign-extended) screen coordinates as a Point structure.</param>
    /// <returns>Window handle (hWnd).</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point pt);
    /// <summary>P/Invoke declaration for user32.dll.SendMessage</summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">Window handle</param>
    /// <param name="msg">Windows message</param>
    /// <param name="wp">WParam</param>
    /// <param name="lp">LParam</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
#endregion
#endregion
```

Comment: It is an answer to *something*, just not this question.

Comment: @Hans: The OP asked for an example of usage of IMessageFilter. I had this at hand.

Comment: Yes, the truth is that I finally implemented the menu in a different way. But thanks anyways :)